# Improve UI when using deferred CSS loading

Tags: css, user-interface, deferred, pagespeed

I've been optimizing a page following the requirements specified in Google Speed Insights. The relevant one to this question is the '***Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content***'.

So, basically in this specific case I am using the `loadDeferredStyles` function mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery).

And by using that the Google PageSpeed rating ends up excellent, BUT... when you load the page it appears without any styles in the first 1 or 2 seconds of loading and after that stylesheets are applied.

My question is, what can I do to make this invisible to the user. I was thinking of either putting an inline `body { opacity: 0 }` and then rewriting it in the CSS, but I am not sure that's the best option. I am also thinking of putting an overlay with a loading gif or something similar, but I am also not sure if that's the ideal thing.

What I want to avoid is the user seeing plain text when the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always '*Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content*' means the page resources are not loading in the correct order.

I cannot help you without a link to the site. None of the suggestions you made are good. and I do not understand what they have to do with render blocking content.

Run your site through [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org).  Then look at the waterfall for .css or .woff (or equivalent) files that are loaded after a javascript file.

### UPDATE

You have a wicked fast server @  17,525,000 Bps.  But 4.5 sec to visually complete is not good.  But tha's what happens when you create a page with 3rd party JavaScript like Bootstrap and jQuery rather than CSS and HTML.

[image: stats pagespeed]

**NEVER** put JS before CSS. JS should be after the HTML just before the closing `</body>` tag wherever possible.

**THIS IS WHAT GOOGLE MEANS BY RENDER BLOCKING.**
Fonts are considered CSS.  All CSS must be loaded before JavaScript because it delays rendering.

[image: WATERFALL]

### UPDATE

There is no reason this page if done correctly could not load in way less than one second.

You really need to learn your BASIC HTML and CSS. Always run a page through the W3C HTML and CSS Valadation Tools. There are rules to doing this.  You are violating so many rules in such horrible ways I'm suprised the page rfenders at all.  The Browser is fixing all the errors and that is why rendering takes 3.5 seconds.  Rendering for this page should not take 100 mS.

**First thing you have to do is eliminate the HTML errors.  Your `<head>` is an absolute mess.**

**EXAMPLE:**  You cannot put this in the `<head>`:

```
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=258875784506817&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

Why is the link to app.css at the bottom of the body????

**Move this link**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://printome.mx/css/app.css"/>
```

to right after the `<title></title>`

The CSS file should only contain CSS that is being used.

Why is there an FB script after the `<body>`, this is horrible.
Move it to just before `</body>` after the HTML.

I do not see any compelling reason to use external fonts when standard web fonts would do just fine, but that's not my call.  I would not use them.

**It appears the font is not being used anyhow.**  It seems to be defaulting to sans-serif.

**DO NOT** use Web Font Loader unless you have a good justifiable reason to do so.

If you want to use Google Fonts do it with a `<link rel>` as shown below:

```
<title>Diseñar y personalizar playeras en minutos | printome.mx</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://printome.mx/css/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Font+Name">
<style>

<style>


  .
```

Comment: The site is [this](https://printome.mx) and the thing is that I use Foundation 6, but without the CSS the JS doesn't fire events correctly and this affects visual elements. I minimized everything in 2 files, app.css and main.js but if I put main.js before app.css I get visual issues as commented. I put app.css in the footer as it drastically increases the Speed Insights result, but as I originally said it shows the page styleless for the first few moments.

Comment: I like to keep CSS very small and put it in the `<head>< style>`.  If kept small caching an external link is not quicker.  Many time I will see "First Paint" before the HTML has finished loading.  Having the CSS in an external file is costing you 200-300 mS.  You server is very fast so even 45K bytes of CSS will load in about 40 mS if in the `<head>`

Comment: The thing is that when I return app.css in the head it lowers the SpeedInsights result considerably. Do you think inlining it would improve that? It's 239kb minified and 44.5kb compressed with gzip for the http transfer. I am not familiar with gzip so I don't know if it would compress it when inline.

Comment: The font is loaded via JS using Webfont Loader asynchronously.

Comment: I do know all the stuff you're telling me, but I've been doing this "bad" stuff, because of the practices mentioned in Google Speed Insights recommendations.

1. The facebook pixel specifically requires to be loaded in `<head>` and it's used for marketing purposes.
2. I put the link out of head, because for some reason it drastically increased my result in Google Speed Insights and that result is really useful for AdWords.
3. If I put only CSS that is being used, my caching would be of no use because new files will be loaded in every section.

Comment: 4. The font is used in the design. What's so bad about the Webfont Loader? It's recommended by Google? Also, if I separate it and put it in a `<link rel` it lowers my Speed Insights result for some reason.

Comment: YOU HAVE MORE PROBLEMS THAN JUST THE FONT.  Google does not recommend using font loader over `<link rel>`, it they say use it  if you need more control, then use it.  Did you move the CSS link to the `<head>'?  Did you fix the HTML errors in the `<head>`?  If you don;t do that Google Insights has nothing valid to work with.  If you do not want my help, ignore my answer.  Do not second guess my answer.  I know what I am doing and you do not.  Your HTML and CSS is horrific.

Comment: If you just put the `<link rel>` in the `<head>` without the CSS being loaded, I can see Google not liking you.  If you would do what I posted in  my answer, you'd see results.  VERY IMPORTANT fix the HTML!!   You do know how to run the W3C HTML Validation tool?